# kendo mvc grid popup editor how to get the model id

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm currently having some problems with the Kendo Grid using a popup template. Hers my code:

index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EmployeeModel>().Name("grid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(55);
    columns.Bound(p => p.FullName).Width(180);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("EmployeeEditor"))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.Id); model.Field(p => p.Id); })
    .Create(create => create.Action("create", "employee"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("read", "employee"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "employee"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("Destroy", "employee"))
)
```

On my custom editor i have a multiselet that calls a static function - GetSuperiorIds - that will load the value property:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().Name("employees").DataTextField("FirstName").DataValueField("Id").Placeholder("Select employees...").AutoBind(true).Events(e => { e.Open("open"); })
        .Value(GetSuperiorIds(XX))
        .DataSource(source => {
            source
                .Read(read => {
                    read.Action("GetEmployees", "employee", new { id = @Html.Raw("${Id}") });
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
    )
```

I need a variable for GetSuperiorIds(**what to put here**), Model.Id returns null.

Originally I was having trouble with the read Action as it also needs the model id. Fortunately, Html.Raw("${Id}") returns the same value but I can't seem to use it as a parameter for the static function.

Is there any other way to get the model id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understand correctly you want `Model.Id` in your pop up right?

Comment: yes please. thats exactly what im looking for

Comment: so `Id` should be hidden or you want to show that?

Comment: definitely hidden, if i can put that value into a variable to supply a static function GetSuperiorIds(xx)

Comment: On your custom Editor template define the Model variable as **@model EmployeeModel** then you will be able to access the ID variable.